# Как в Java быстро проверить значение в массиве?

Tags: java

Всем привет. В `PHP` быстро можно проверить значение в массиве вот так

```
<?php
if (in_array("needle", ["value1", "value2", "value3"])) {
    // ...
}
```

... еще много разных функций.
Меня интересует как в языке `Java` можно быстро на лету создать такую же конструкцию.
Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы удалил из вопроса слово быстро))

Comment: если вам нужно выполнить такую проверку, то в качестве структуры данных стоит выбирать не массив, а Set (hashset). Дело в том, что несортированный массив проверяет наличие элемента простым перебором, получаем сложность O(n) , что совсем нехорошо. Что касается hashset, то писк осуществляется через хеш-функцию, тогда в лучшем случае (если не учитывать возможные коллизии), сложность O(1). разница очевидна

Comment: @Дмитрий разницы нет что использовать, list, set это не принципиально. есть строка, её значение нужно быстро (для программиста) проверить с несколько другими строками, то есть проверить соотвествие одного значение с максимум 5 другими значениями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (someList.contains(someValue)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ: а как можно на лету создать `someList` более элегантно не подскажите?

Comment: `List.of("value1", "value2", "value3")`